# TensorFlow on Anaconda running on Windows 7

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, windows-7-x64

I installed the 64-bit version Anaconda (v1.6.11) on my windows 7 64-bit machine. This comes with python3.6.3. I then installed CPU version of tensorflow v1.2.1 from Anaconda Install package option (not using conda from command prompt) . When I execute the following code:

```
# Initializers
sigma = 1
weight_initializer = tf.variance_scaling_initializer(mode="fan_avg", 
distribution="uniform", scale=sigma)
bias_initializer = tf.zeros_initializer()
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-22d819110f53> in <module>()
  1 # Initializers
  2 sigma = 1
----> 3 weight_initializer = tf.variance_scaling_initializer(mode="fan_avg", 
distribution="uniform", scale=sigma)
  4 bias_initializer = tf.zeros_initializer()

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 
'variance_scaling_initializer'
```

However, tf.variance_scaling_initializer does exist on tensorflow website. Prior to executing the above, I was able to
run:

```
import tensorflow as tf
#Session
net = tf.InteractiveSession()
# Placeholders
n_stocks = X_train.shape[1]  # number of independent variables / IVs
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, n_stocks])
Y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None])
```

So I guess tensorflow is working within Anaconda environment.

Q1: What am I doing wrong?  Help please.

Q2: As you can see I am trying to run tensorflow within Anaconda on a 64-bit Windows 7? What is the best practice please? How do the experenced developers set up their python+tensorflow environment? On linux through pip?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that "tf.variance_scaling_initializer" is now available as "tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer" in later TensorFlow versions. The associated keywords have also changed.
[Please see here for details:](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/variance_scaling_initializer)